# How do you make an SDS for a milligram sample synthesized for the first time?

Tags: safety

There is this impurity detected by GCMS that we got custom synthesized at a 15 mg level. There's this absolutely tiny vial that needs to be couriered to the lab for further analysis.

Fedex insists on an SDS. Other than identity and a few basic details nothing more is known at this point about the sample (e.g. flash point, LD50 etc.)

But of course, the quantity is 15 mg so one would not reasonably anticipate a hazard. I am not aware of an existing SDS nor do we have enough information on the hazards. For all we know this substance has no commercial uses and may not have been manufactured at scale ever before. That is why we had to do a custom synthesis (Sigma / Merck etc.did not offer it in their catalogs)

How would the chemists deal with a situation like this one?  It seems to transcend the reasonableness standard.

Comment: Of course it depends on dose and pathway of application when LD50 is reached (e.g., [botolinum toxin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botulinum_toxin)).  If your compound is an analogue/homologue in structure of already known compounds, may you *infer* from their SDS suitable precautions and mention that these are preliminary?  If you have their CAS registry numbers and know some Python, [find_sds](https://github.com/khoivan88/find_sds) is one helpful tool to collect such data (you might need to remove the explicit version request for entry idna in file requirements.txt to get it installed).

Comment: I have sent - and received - many samples and I've always filled in terms as non flammable non explosive etc. Somewhere, but I forgot if it was in an accompanying letter, I've made clear that it was *a new compound for academical research ONLY*. I've never run into troubles of sort.

Comment: @Alchimista And that's how it should be! Sadly sometimes the people involved follow scripted processes: Chemicals = SDS. Maybe this is because it's an international air shipment? Who knows!

Comment: @curious_cat Perhaps in this case. But what I mean is that the SDS is replaced by an accompanying letter (in addition to the shopping formular where you keep low profile in all entries and describe your sample as *for research only*. The letters can be a copy of your research correspondence to the recipient, this I was doing to prevent problems at the custom, especially in certain times (anthrax crisis, for example). But it is now quite some time I am not sending/receiving by couriers...